# changing uiviewcontroller views frame?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Whatever Im trying to my view controller won't appear offscreen (as it I want to, because I have a handler(menu) that will make the animation from offscreen to onscreen. After realising (from other posts) that I can't change a views frame before it appears, makes sense to use this approach:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
//self.view.frame = CGRectInset(self.view.frame, 100, 50);
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50);
}
```

But still, it is presented exactly on screen as any standard view controller would (0,0,width, height)

How to solve?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have the method `willLayoutSubviews`: or `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

> Called to notify the view controller that its view is about to layout
>   its subviews.When a view's bounds change, the view adjusts the position of its subviews.

So instead of doing it in view will appear,over ride the willLayoutSubviews:

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{

    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

      [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];

}
```

Comment: This definitely works, so I marked it as answer. Just not in my case:( Im still struggling with custom animations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33175681/custom-transition-not-working-optimal-presentviewcontrollercompletion-delayed

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered adding all of your views to another view, functioning as a container view, and then adding that one view to your view controller's view? Then you'd be able to position that container view freely before it appears.

Answer (score 0):

You could access the ViewControllers view property and set it in the  `loadView()` and it will only be set once and therefore not messing up any custom animations.

> The view controller calls this method when its view property is requested but is currently nil. This method loads or creates a view and assigns it to the view property.

Because `viewWillLayoutSubviews()` would be setting the frame every time subviews are laid out.

```
override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()
    self.view.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.origin.x,
    y: self.view.bounds.origin.y,
    width: self.view.bounds.width,
    height: self.view.bounds.height * 0.8 
}
```